# Display image from flask send_file function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I use Flask send_file to send an image to the client like this:

```
@app.route('/get-cut-image',methods=["GET"])
def get_cut_img():
   response = make_response(send_file(file_path,mimetype='image/png'))
   response.headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding']='base64'
   return response
```

and in React I use axios to read the request

```
try {
  const dataImage = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:5000/get-cut-image"
  );
  this.setState({
      images: dataImage.data,
    });
  console.log(dataImage.data);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

`console.log(dataImage.data)` return this:
[image]

I need to render the image later using `<img src={this.state.images}/>` but it does not display anything. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You dataImage.data is Binary large object, so you should try:

```js
try {
  const dataImage = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:5000/get-cut-image"
  );
  
  const blob = await dataImage.data.blob()
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  this.setState({
      images: url,
    });
  console.log(url);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I got this error: ```TypeError: "dataImage.data.blob is not a function"```

Comment: Sorry, you image is base64 string, don't use my code snippet, use your code. Pls, try <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.images}`} /> instead of <img src={this.state.images}/>

Comment: did you mean ```<img src="{data:image/png;base64,${this.state.images}}}" />``` ? I tried that but it doesnt display anything....

Comment: There are just 2 curly braces after this.state.images in ```<img src="{data:image/png;base64,${this.state.images}}" />```  component.

Comment: fix that but not much help :( Or is ist because the binary data is too large?

Comment: @HaAnTran Plz, can you try ```const blob = await dataImage.blob()```, then ```const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)```?

Answer (score 0):

The image sent from the flask app can be simply displayed by `<img src={"http://localhost:5000/get-cut-image"}/>`.